# SelectedIndex add controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

Based on a choice of "Other" in a dropdown I want to add a label and textbox to a `<p>` tag. I have added `runat=server` in the `<p>` tag.

```
    Protected Sub deptDdl_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles deptDdl.SelectedIndexChanged
        'If the user chooses other for the department type add
        'a label and textbox to allow them to fill in a department not listed

        If deptDdl.SelectedValue.ToString = "Other" Then
            Dim deptLbl As Label = New Label
            deptLbl.Text = "Enter the Department Name"
            Dim deptTb As TextBox = New TextBox
            deptTb.MaxLength = 20

            Page.FindControl("m_ContentPlaceHolder1_deptPtag").Controls.AddAt(2, deptLbl)
            Page.FindControl("m_ContentPlaceHolder1_deptPtag").Controls.AddAt(3, deptTb)
        End If
    End Sub
```

I keep getting an unhandled exception stating Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What am I missing?

Comment: Tip: You don't need `As X = New X`. You can just do `As New X`. So `Dim deptLbl As New Label()` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `<p>`-tag is `runat=server` you should be able to reference it in the codebehind -file directly. Give it an ID `deptPtag`, then this should be autogenerated in the designer.vb-file:

```
Protected WithEvents deptPtag As Global.System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl
```

But you also have to ensure that your dynamic controls are recreated on every postback(latest in Page_Load, events are too late for reloading the ViewState). Otherwise you won't be able to read `deptTb.Text` or handle it's `TextChanged`-event. 
The ID must be the same on every postback to correctly load the `ViewState`.

My answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163846/findcontrol-and-inamingcontainer) explains your `NullReferenceException`.
It's a special behaviour of `FindControl` from within a MasterPage's content-page.