# Cannot find TextBox on Page

Tags: asp.net

I have a textbox on a page but when i use

```
TextBox formTextBox = Page.FindControl(textBox) as TextBox;
```

it comes back `null`. Is there a way around this? I know the control is on the page but i cant find it.

Thanks

Comment: You know that the control is on the page, but **where**? Can you shouw your markup? Apart from that, are you using `MasterPages`? If this is true, have a look at my answer on another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8163964/284240

Comment: Is it in a content area of a master page?

Comment: Yes, It is in a content area of a master page

Comment: Here is a [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx) on how to reference master page content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using `MasterPages` and this control is in a page sitting in a `ContentPlaceholder`, you cannot get the reference to the control via `FindControl` directly, since the only control in the page's `ControlCollection` is the MasterPage itself. 
That makes sense. You cannot guarantee an ID to be unique when the control is on the top level of a page with MasterPage, because other ContentPages might as well have a control with this ID and `FindControl` could today return another control than tomorrow.

If you look at the [`NamingContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx) of the Control you want to find, you see that in case of a `MasterPage` it is the `ContentPlaceHolder` and in case of a "normal" Page it is the Page itself.

So you need to get a reference to the MasterPage's ContentPlaceholder first before you could find the control via FindControl:

```
Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("TextBox1");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx

**But why don't you simply reference your control directly**? For example:

```
this.TextBox1.Text = "Hello World";
```

By the way, this is derived from [my own answer on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8163964/284240).

Comment: I was curious why he didn't just reference it directly too.

Answer (score 0):

One of two things is happening... either the control is not being found (this is the most likely) or it is not returning a `TextBox` object.

The thing to remember about `FindControl` is that it is NOT recursive... it will only look at the top-level child controls.  So, if your text box is nested inside another control, it will not be found. you can [read the MSDN docs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw.aspx).

You may want to make your own version of FindControl that will search inside nested controls--implementing such a method is trivial and can be found easily using your google-foo

Comment: I'm sure a recursive finder already exists, he only need look for it.

Comment: Hi, It is only neseted in a div.

Comment: @jcolebrand other people have written such, but it does not exist in the API.  you have to implement it yourself or borrow someone else's

Comment: @WesleySkeen then you'll need to search inside that div. Give it an id and runat=server (so an <asp:Panel)

Comment: @jcolebrand: A div (or Panel) does not implement INamingContainer.

Comment: @TimSchmelter ??? I could've sworn I've used it before for that ... MSDN! I must be thinking of a Content then, since they get translated into the subsumed parental CPH. Interesting. Either that, or I'm thinking of my UserControls.

Comment: @TimSchmelter no, I grokked that. I just thought I had used one for that purpose before. Also, you probably didn't see my edit while typing your response. For future visitors wanting to see those INamingContainer objects: http://i.imgur.com/LtZnC.png

Comment: @jcolebrand: What i wanted to say is, a NamingContainer ensures that all controls IDs are unique in this container. It creates unique IDs in itself. Then you need to use FindControl on this container control to find your nested control. But since Panel does not implements it, you can be sure that it would not help to FindControl on a Panel. The problem here is that the page is inside of a ContentPlaceholder of a MasterPage. So the NamingContainer of it is not the page(and not the div/panel) but the ContentPlaceholder. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9520061/284240

Answer (score 0):

Put a place holder around the text box in the markup, like this:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="MyPlaceHolder" runat="server>
  <asp:TextBox ID="MyTextBox" runat="server" />
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Then you can fin the text box using:

```
TextBox formTextBox = MyPlaceHolder.FindControl("MyTextBox") as TextBox;
```