# Getting error in ASP.Net page

Tags: asp.net

Can you please let me know why the following piece of code is not working, I am getting the  error message when the debugger past the variable "strStatus". The error message is: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Can you please help. Thanks - Yagya

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Y0130_chkNew.Checked == true)
        {
            bool isChecked = true; // This is required for later retrieval.

            string strAction = "Reporting";
            string strFromRole = ddSelectRole.SelectedValue;

            string TxtBoxID = myProject.getTextBox(strAction, strPath);
            TextBox txtb = new TextBox();
            txtb = (TextBox)Page.FindControl(TxtBoxID);
            string strStatus = txtb.Text;

            string ddID = myProject.getDropDown(strAction, strPath);
            DropDownList ddLst = new DropDownList;
            ddLst = (DropDownList)Page.FindControl(ddID);
            string strForwardRole = ddLst.SelectedValue;

            // Call the function now
            my.updateXML(strFromRole, strAction, strStatus, strForwardRole, strPath);

        }

    }
```

Comment: What does `string TxtBoxID = myProject.getTextBox(strAction, strPath);`?  Can you show that method? Apart from that, `Page.FindControl(TxtBoxID);` returns null what is the reason for your exception. `FindControl` does not search controls recursively, only in the given `NamingContainer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Page.FindControl(TxtBoxID);` returns null what is the reason for your exception. `FindControl` does not search controls recursively, only in the given `NamingContainer`.

If the control is not nested in another `NamingContainer` on the page(f.e. a `GridViewRow`), there's no reason at all to use `FindControl` since you could reference it directly:

```
string strStatus = TextBox1.Text; // assuming TextBox1 is declared on the aspx
```

If you're using `MasterPages` the `NamingContainer` of  controls in the `ContentPage` is not the page but the `ContenPlaceHolder`:

[Cannot find TextBox on Page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9520061/284240)

Comment: Hi - The function getTextBox retrieved the ID of the text box from an XML file for given parameters. I double checked that the ID is retrieved successfull and is present in the web page. Also please note that the IDs of the controls are unique across entire project. Not sure what is wrong here. I am using master page only to have consistent look and feel and for site navigation purpose. You have  a point here. Let me check if using content place holder in the master page fix this problem. Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: Finally it worked by using the following statement:
txtb = (TextBox)Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl(TxtBoxID);

Answer (score 0):

You are finding a control using a function and possibly its returning a textbox id which doesnt existin on page . Please try to debug and see what textbox id you are getting from myProject.getTextBox function and if that exist on page .

Answer (score 0):

Final Code:
            if (Y0130_chkNew.Checked == true)
            {
                string TxtBoxID = "Y0140_txtStatus";
                TextBox txtb = new TextBox();
                txtb = (TextBox)Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl(TxtBoxID);
                string strStatus = txtb.Text;

```
            string ddID = "Y0150_ddOwnerRoleAssignment";
            DropDownList ddLst = new DropDownList();             
            ddLst = (DropDownList)Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl(ddID);            
            string strForwardRole = ddLst.SelectedValue;                       
        }
```