# .NET Active Server Page FindControl is always returning nothing

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I created a simple page with one button, then on the click event have it use FindControl, to get a reference to itself.  But..... FindControl is returning nothing.
code

```
Protected Sub EntryDoor1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles EntryDoor1.Click
    Dim control = FindControl("EntryDoor1")
    control.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Might help if you posted some of the `.aspx` with the control you're trying to find.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you've said that you want "a reference to itself", i assume that you want a reference to the button that has caused the click-event.

The easiest is to use the `sender` argument, because that's always the source control:

```
Dim button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
```

But when the button is on top of the page(as in this case), the reference to the control is automatically created in the partial `designer.vb` file:

```
 EntryDoor1.Visible = False
```

So why using `FindControl` if you have a direct reference anyway?!

**Edit**:

Just for the sake of completeness. The behaviour you're describing can only have one reason: You're trying to use `FindControl` in a `ContentPage` of a `MasterPage`. [This is a special case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163846/findcontrol-and-inamingcontainer/8163964#8163964), you need to get the reference to the `ContentPlaceholder` first. Then  you can use `FindControl` for your `Button`:

```
Dim button = DirectCast(Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("EntryDoor1"), Button)
```

But again, this is pointless since you have the reference in the page directly.